# Do I need to specify the path of my file in the fopen function?

Tags: c, fopen

FILE *fopen(const char *filename, const char *mode);

I saw that some people only put the name of the file inside the "filename" part, some others put the entire path

example

> FILE *fopen("mytext.txt", r);
>
> FILE *fopen("/myfolder/mytext.txt", r);

which is the correct one?

Comment: It depends on the OS. (that's the reason why the first argument is *just* a string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file is in current directory when you run the program - no.

If it's not - yes, you will need to specify the path (absolute or relative to current directory)